# building a 3d model viewer android?

Tags: android, view, opengl-es, model, viewer

I'm trying to build a model viewer in opengl, but got stumped... I basically just want to build my own app that can load a custom model in .off or .obj format and display it on my tablet.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? Android Apps themselves? Opengl API? The file formats? You are going to have to be more specific.

Comment: thats about as specific as it gets. I'm not looking for a complicated answer. Just a little direction to the right path. If you search the market ("3d viewer"), you see a few free apps that have the desired basic look. That's where I'm trying to get to, but got stumped in the coding process. So I'm looking to see if anyone can point me in the right direction so I can start over from scratch.

Comment: @SpicyWeenie I'm stuck at the same point as you, if you can, please contact with me and your experience in this field will be very helpful for me. Tx in advance. whoose.daddy@gmail.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at open source code for examples:

OBJloaderforAnd:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/objloaderforand/

Android-GL

http://code.google.com/p/android-gl/

and search Stackoverflow before asking questions:

[Android OpenGL .OBJ file loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162667/android-opengl-obj-file-loader)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505025/load-a-obj-file-on-android

Comment: Ummm, yeeeeah... the question is in the context and there's no need to be rude about this TryTry

Comment: Not rude: As stated by the Flag **Not a Real Question** _It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form._ I wasn't saying your question isn't a real question...only, it is likely to be flagged as that based on the definition we use, in the way you formulated your question in its current state.

Comment: I clarified it more on my comment to PeterT TryTry. It was a basic question asking for a basic answer. I've seen people ask specific, understandable questions, yet the majority of responders "over-think," or think they have to come up with an exhaustively confusing reply. And often, reading comprehension isnt their strong point, so they ask "can you be more specific?" If the question or whatever is broad, match it. Ask an engaging question back. But don't drown them in technicalities. Too many responders try to act like Mark Zuckerberg from the facebook movie.

Comment: First of all, you didn't state a real question in your "question".  So by definition it is "not a real question".  Instead of adding it in a comment, you could edit your "question" to include the actual question.  Second, the answer to your implied original question would span multiple chapters in a book (e.g. [*Beginning Android Games*](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1430230428)).  That is certainly "overly broad".  A reasonably narrow question would be "where can I learn about Android 3D programming and 3D file formats?".  However, that would still be off-topic for stackoverflow.