# 3D Model of Earth in Android

Tags: android

I'm relatively new to Android, and am just wondering how to go about creating a 3D model of Earth. My idea is to have a 3D Earth that can be rotated by the user on the screen.

I'm not a pro in graphic design, so I'm not even sure how to go about solving this. If anyone could shed some light in regards to which programs and methods to use, that would be wonderful.

Comment: That might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756792/building-a-3d-model-viewer-android

Comment: You can build .obj 3d model. Look at this [Min 3D Library](https://code.google.com/p/min3d/) Where You can do this.