# How to use .obj file for animation in Android?

Tags: android, 3d

I have a Wavefront OBJ file that I want to display on my screen.
How can I do that?
Any kind of link would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android OpenGL .OBJ file loader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162667/android-opengl-obj-file-loader)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these links:
[OBJ loader for Android](http://sourceforge.net/projects/objloaderforand/files/)

[Android opengl obj loaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162667/android-opengl-obj-file-loader)