# use .obj file from blender 2.62+, in java with Eclipse for Android openGL ES

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, .obj, blender-2.61

I have looked near and far for a solution to this problem. There seems to be ways to do this using a older version of Blender. I do not want to use an earlier version of Blender, I want to use 2.62.0 and above.

Basically I want to use Blender to create objects to use in my Android applications. I will be using openGL ES in Java. The easier to implement this the better, I am not trying to re-invent the wheel here.

- Blend2Java does not work for Blender 2.5+
- Java.net seems to be down for maintenance so I cannot find any Java3D resources that will assist
- Other 3D Graphics software is just not up to par with Blender and I feel that other software will encounter similar issues
- I have also tried min3D and that did not work for me either
- An asset pipeline might be nice but at this point I will load image by image if I have to

Could someone please give me some options that will work with blender 2.62 or a run down of the steps that need to be taken to accomplish this. I have decent experience with Java but it is getting to the point where I can no longer keep my sanity.

Last but not least ...

Thank you all here on Stack Overflow and I hope for some good posts as future reference

Comment: Clarify your question. Once you export a model from your favorite modeling tool, you forget about it (the tool). `Blender2Java` is a blender _port_ and I don't understand why you need a Blender variant written in Java. `min3D` looks like a (not-so-minimal) framework on top of Android's ES 1.0 capabilities. Now, how does an _asset pipeline_ fit here?

Comment: Okay sorry for the misunderstanding. I need a blender port like Blender2Java, but Blend2Java does not work on newer versions of Blander.

I would love to use min3D but I cannot get it to work. The reason I cant get it to work is because I cannot download or even find the Java class library packages needed. [link](http://code.google.com/p/min3d/) My intelligence feels destroyed by not understanding something this simple. I cant extract the files from the .apk and that is the only thing you can download other than svn/trunk/*.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for an obj loader for android? There are several mentioned here:

[Android OpenGL .OBJ file loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162667/android-opengl-obj-file-loader)

Comment: I think I don't understand the concept of a .obj loader. I want to take the .obj and convert the actual text to Java format. For example a cube that I created from scratch in Java in openGL is called cube.java. If I have a cube.obj and cube.mtl that was from Blender I want a program to take these and create/convert all the object data to a cube.java class. This created class will be able to be rendered in me renderer.java class via Cube cube = new Cube(); then drawn via onDrawFrame() .... cube.draw(gl);.