# How to make an offline indoor map for Android?

Tags: android

I want to make a small map like the one in the picture with buttons to go to a different screen. How to do something similar but in 2D?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using some kind 3D viewers, with your custom 3D file, taking advantage of android openGL. [This post may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162667/android-opengl-obj-file-loader)