# How to render the 3 D models from CT scan DICOM files on the marker for medical augment reality purpose in Android application

Tags: android, augmented-reality, dicom, artoolkit, android-augmented-reality

I am new to android and ARToolkit.I have to develop the android application which can augment and render the 3D models from CT scan images in DICOM format on the detected marker. I am using ARToolkit SDK for my purpose. But don't how to proceed with the dicom files and render the 3D model on marker. Someone please suggest some approach. Any sort of help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What have you got so far? Do you have 3d models from the CTs or are you supposed to make them?

Comment: I tried to use AndAr (https://code.google.com/archive/p/andar/) as my reference point. It uses .obj and .mtl files. So in my case i wanted to generate 3D models from the CTs. Right now i don't have any 3D models from the CTs. I am supposed to make them and store it in .obj and .mtl format. I searched on internet about how to generate 3D mdels from CTs (not just visualize only). Some are talking about some software but nothing seems to be promising. So if you could help me regarding this, it will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the following process; 
Figure out a tool for segmentation. This is the process whereby you will build a 3d model of subset of the data depending on density. For example, you will build a model of the ribs of a chest CT. You should do this outside of Android and then figure out how to move it later. You can use tools like ITK and VTK to learn how to do this stage.

If you want to avoid the ITK/VTK learning curve, use GDCM (grass roots dicom) to learn how to load a DICOM series. With this approach you can have a 3D array of density points in your app in a few hours. At this point you can forget about the DICOM and just work on the numbers. You still have the segmentation problem.

You can look at the NIH app ImageVis3D which has source code and see what there approach is.

Once you have a segmented dataset, conversion to a standard format is not too hard and you will be on your way.

What is the 'detected marker' you refer to? If you have a marker in the image set to aid in segmentation, you can work on detection from the 3d dataset you get back from loading the dicom data.

Once you have the processes worked out, you can then see how to apply it all to Android.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a little old but, recommended for a start: [Android OpenGL .OBJ file loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162667/android-opengl-obj-file-loader)

I was wondering too about building a CustomView to address your needs, since in a CV you can display anything.

Comment: Can you please elaborate somewhat? Also how can we get obj file from the CT's Dicom files?

Comment: I am really sorry, I am as lost as you are, or else. As I stated, "for a start"... Maybe with Android OpenGL you can build your own Dicom file loader. Or investigating the possibilities of a CustomView. These were my guesses, based on what I currently know about those sujects. If someone has a better guess, or answers, I will be glad for you, and will learn as you will.

Comment: @PraveenKumar please check the answer you think it was helpful to solve your problem. Thank you.